# the program do not access ValidatingEditor and InvalidValueException

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am using DevExpress DataGrid
I'm filling it from excel.. If the user keep the field Name empty i need to give him an error message.. this my code:

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;

string FirstName = "First Name";
string FatherName = "Father Name";
string LastName = "Last Name";
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\pc\\Documents\\Emp.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes\"";

            con.Open();
            DataTable dtSchema;
            dtSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand ("select * FROM [" + dtSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]", con);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(Command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }   

private void gridView3_ValidatingEditor(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BaseContainerValidateEditorEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        if(view.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "FirstName") 
        {
            string FirName = (e.Value.ToString());
            if(FirName == null) 
            {
                e.Valid = false;
                e.ErrorText = "Enter a First Name";
            }
        }
    }



private void gridView3_InvalidValueException(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.InvalidValueExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do not perform any default action 
        e.ExceptionMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ExceptionMode.NoAction;
        //Show the message with the error text specified 
        MessageBox.Show(e.ErrorText);
    }
```

The problem is when I run the program.. the code do not access this code and it's not showing an error..
Could someone notice where's my fault ?
Thank you so much

Comment: You need to show the code where you hooked up the `ValidatingEditor` and `InvalidValueException` handlers.

Comment: Sorry I'm new in c#.. I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: No problems. In order for the 2 methods in your question to be executed, you need to assign them to the `ValidatingEditor` and `InvalidValueException` events on the DataGrid. We need to see how you are doing that. You may have done that through the designer, or you may have done it directly in code (maybe in your forms constructor).

Comment: I edited my answer.. That's all what I wrote.
I double clicked on ValidatingEditor and InvalidValueException in the events in the designer where it opened the code .. 
I don't know if that could help You to find the error..
I really appreciate your help

Comment: Somewhere in your code you should have 2 lines like `gridView3.InvalidValueException += gridView3_InvalidValueException` and `gridView3.ValidatingEditor += gridView3_ValidatingEditor`. Can you confirm that is correct? Can you also confirm you have placed a break point on the first line of both methods in your question and that the break points are not hit.

Comment: Are these two lines calling the InvalidValueException event and the InvalidValueException ?

Do I have Write them in the simpleButton1_Click ?

And yes The breakpoint shows that everything is write except passing in these two methods

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't answer your question given the information you have provided. However, there are a number of things you should investigate to figure out the issue.

EDIT: added point 3.

1. Check that you have assigned handlers to the `InvalidValueException` and `ValidatingEditor` events on `gridView3`. You have indicated you have done this through the designer, so you should be able to search your code base and verify you can find the following lines:

   `gridView3.InvalidValueException += gridView3_InvalidValueException`
   `gridView3.ValidatingEditor += gridView3_ValidatingEditor`
2. Put a breakpoint at the top of both methods and verify that the handlers are being called - i.e. you are not just relying on your validation working, as opposed to verifying your handlers are being called.
3. Read the DevExpress documentation on the [ValidatingEditor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_ValidatingEditortopic) and [InvalidValueException](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_InvalidValueExceptiontopic) events to make sure you have a correct understanding of how they are triggered.

Comment: ok now I got your point.. 

I added this code in the button click event:

   gridView3.ValidatingEditor += new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BaseContainerValidateEditorEventHandler(gridView3_ValidatingEditor);
   gridView3.InvalidValueException += new InvalidValueExceptionEventHandler(gridView3_InvalidValueException);

But still.. It do not access the method. The program stop when the button click event end

Comment: The button click event handler is not the right place to do this. I'd suggest you add those lines into the constructor of your form.